# change Byte[] values in JNI with android studio

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, native

i want to reference a parameter, Byte[], in a JNI function and replace values of them.
The declaration of JNI is below.

> public native void imageprocessing(long inputImage, long inputImage2, long outputImage, long outputImage2, **Byte[] sim**);

The **sim** is the target what i want to change.
The interface of it is below.

> Java_com_example_duru_opencvtest_MainActivity_imageprocessing(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance,
>                                                                 jlong inputImage, jlong inputImage2, jlong outputImage, jlong outputImage2, **jobjectArray sim**)

it uses jobjectArray type and i want to **put int type values of native language into sim object**.

so i my method is

```
        jbyteArray byte_array = env->NewByteArray(4);
        env->SetByteArrayRegion(byte_array, 0, 4, (jbyte*)tempSim);
        jobjectArray object_array = env->NewObjectArray(4, env->FindClass("java/lang/Byte"), byte_array);

        /* ERROR
        (*env).SetObjectArrayElement(sim, 0, (jobject)object_array[0]);
        (*env).SetObjectArrayElement(sim, 1, (jobject)object_array[1]);
        (*env).SetObjectArrayElement(sim, 2, (jobject)object_array[2]);
        (*env).SetObjectArrayElement(sim, 3, (jobject)object_array[3]);
        */
```

tempSim is 'int tempSim[4]' and Sim also has 4 length.

> (*env).SetObjectArrayElement(sim, 0, **(jobject)object_array[0]**);

The bold part occur syntax error than the other part have no problem?

Comment: You can't access Java arrays like that from native code. In this case you need to use the `GetObjectArrayElement` function. Although I don't really see what the purpose of `byte_array` and `object_array` is. Why don't you just pass each of `tempSim`'s values to `Byte.valueOf` instead?

Comment: Note: `NewByteArray` is for a primative array (Java: `byte[]`; JNI: `jbytearray`), not an object array (Java: `Byte[]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jclass javaLangByteClass = env->FindClass("java/lang/Byte");
jmethodID javaLangByteConstructor = env->GetMethodID(javaLangByteClass , "<init>", "(B)Ljava/lang/Byte;")
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
   jobject nextElement = env->NewObject(javaLangByteClass, javaLangByteConstructor, (jbyte)tempSim[i]);
   env->SetObjectArrayElement(sim, i, nextElement);
   env->DeleteLocalRef(nextElement);
}
```

See the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53387465/change-byte-values-in-jni-with-android-studio/53388903?noredirect=1#comment93656524_53388903) below: **Byte.valueOf()** may be more efficient than the constructor:

```
jclass javaLangByteClass = env->FindClass("java/lang/Byte");
jmethodID javaLangByteStaticValueOf = env->GetStaticMethodID(javaLangByteClass , "valueOf", "(B)Ljava/lang/Byte;")
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
   jobject nextElement = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(javaLangByteClass, javaLangByteStaticValueOf, (jbyte)tempSim[i]);
   env->SetObjectArrayElement(sim, i, nextElement);
   env->DeleteLocalRef(nextElement);
}
```

Comment: `Byte.valueOf(byte)` should generally be preferred over `new Byte(byte)`, as the former caches `Byte` instances of all possible `byte` values.

Comment: how can i use **Byte.valueof()** in JNI?? i try to it but nothing works. and  is it possible the method, 'Byte.valueof()', replace the javaLangByteConstructor line? since this statement occur runtime error.

Comment: thank you for your help, but still have a runtime error at `jmethodID javaLangByteStaticValueOf = env->GetMethodID(javaLangByteClass , "valueOf", "(B)Ljava/lang/Byte;");` i think that signature is problem so i change the return type,**Ljava/lang/Byte**, to **String** since it is strange that same as return type parameter type. but it didn't work..

Comment: Sorry, copy/paste mistake. We need `GetStaticMethodID()`